# Angular: Trigger events on nested objects of object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let say I have a object name `myobject`

This object has a property `leveloneobject` this object is simply a map between objectid and corresponding object, like below

```
myobject : {
 leveloneobject: {
   objectid1: {
      property1: value1,
      property2: value2
   },
   objectid2: {
      property1: value1,
      property2: value2
   },
   objectidn: {
      property1: value1,
      property2: value2
   }
 }
}
```

Now I want to achieve something like

```
myobject.leveloneobject[objectId].register(function(err, result) {
});
```

It is some sort of an API (myobject is global api object). How can I do this.

And other scenario, I have to trigger some event in following way

```
myobject.leveloneobject[objectId].on('someevent', function(event, data) {
});
```

The nested level can go more deep.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Your question is totally unclear, but you may be looking for something like [`$scope.$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Comment: myobject is an API function and that is having property leveloneobject, which is a map between objectid and corresponding objects